# Laravel WHERE query for a single column result

Tags: php, laravel, routes, eloquent

I have the following controller which is supposed to return all users who are not verified yet.

```
public function getUserRequests()
{
    $userRequests = User::where('status' ,"Not Verified");

    foreach($userRequests as $user)
    {
        echo $user->name;   
    }
}
```

The output is an empty page. What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `get()` method to get data:

```
$userRequests = User::where('status' ,"Not Verified")->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this: you need to use [`get()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#retrieving-results) method for fetch the data.

```
$userRequests = User::where('status', '=', 'Not Verified')->get();
```

[Laravel Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#where-clauses)

Answer (score 0):

> You have to use `get()` method to returns the data.

So, your function should be some thing like this.

```
public function getUserRequests()
{
    $userRequests = User::where('status', "Not Verified")->get();

    foreach($userRequests as $user)
    {
        echo $user->name;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple one way is,

```
public function getUserRequests()
{
   $userRequests = User::where('status' ,"Not Verified")->get(['name]);

  foreach($userRequests as $user)
  {
    echo $user->name;   
  }
}
```

or

```
public function getUserRequests()
{
   $userRequests = User::where('status' ,"Not Verified")->select('name')->get();

  foreach($userRequests as $user)
  {
    echo $user->name;   
  }
}
```